Does REIT ETF count as "Hard Assets"?
I'm reading "The Permanent Portfolio" by Harry Browne, in Chapter 6 it talks about diversification strategies,

Most assets held by investors are so-called “paper assets.” A paper
asset is essentially someone else's promise to pay back a debt in the
future (as with bonds) or in recognition of some ownership interest in
assets under someone else's control (as with stocks). In contrast to
paper assets, “hard assets” are physical objects or property that can
be held in one's own possession and retain value independent of what
the value of a currency or other paper may be doing. A hard asset can
be something as simple as gold or silver bullion coins tucked away in
a safe deposit box, or something more involved like real estate that
an investor can also use to generate income.
...
Many diversification strategies fail because investors:

Take too much risk in a single asset class.
Hold assets that are exposed to the same types of risk.
Use false assumptions about asset class correlations.
Hold no hard assets.
Have little or no cash reserves.


My questions

For rule 4, I'm wondering whether REIT ETF should be considered as "paper assets" or "hard assets"? Or it falls into rule 2, share the same risk as other stocks?
Why is only gold included in the portfolio instead of other "hard assets"?


Note that many people would disagree with the claim you have quoted. One can certainly succeed without hard assets other. than the house they are living in (if they choose to buy) and a small number of bank accounts. And normally the house you occupy should not be counted as an investment, though it can be borrowed against.

Also, "gold in a safety deposit box" is not the best example, because it still carries counterparty risk.  US Private Vaults, anyone?


For rule 4, I'm wondering whether REIT ETF should be considered as "paper assets" or "hard assets"? Or it falls into rule 2, share the same risk as other stocks?

REIT is a paper asset. You own a unit in the trust, not an actual real property. You rely on someone's promise to manage it, pay you the dividends, and redeem your equity or transfer your ownership interest to someone else if you're interested in cashing out (REITs can be traded on secondary market or behave like mutual funds).

Why is only gold included in the portfolio instead of other "hard assets"?

Gold is given as an example, another example given is real estate. Hard assets are tangible assets that you own and control physically and directly.

Concerning "retain value independent of what the value of a currency or other paper may be doing": if you have an industry that fails, residential property in that area won't retain its value.
E. g. consider having real estate property in Detroit. I am not from there, but I think the value of residential property there hasn't increased much in the last decades.
Other examples in Germany: The area around Ludwigshafen/Mannheim is greatly dominated by BASF, and the area around Wolfsburg by Volkswagen.
If you work there AND have employer's stock AND have a house there, you failed to diversify: if your employer gets in trouble, your employment might be gone, your investment decreases in value and your house as well.

Note that the "hard vs paper" distinction has nothing to do with the risk of the property devaluing, it's about the counterparty risk.  Possession of gold in your own safe vs gold in a bank box you have the keys to vs ownership of gold in someone else's vault that you have no access to and have no possession of.  Not gold vs real estate.

@BenVoigt In this case, what makes a house or a plot of land effectively yours? Your name in a public register. So is real estate "hard" or "paper"?

The answer to that might be different for a residence vs investment property, and the difference is physical control.
